# How to create Backup Batch file that copys only modified files & delete the dest files/folders that do not exist in the source?

Tags: batch-file, window, backup, batch-processing

I want to create a backup Batch file that meets these requirements:

Requirement:

```
1-Only copy the source files if the source file got modified.

2-If the destination contains the files/folders that do not exist in the source, then the destination files/folders will be deleted.

3-Copies all subdirectories, even if they are empty.

4-If something happened that make the coping process uncompleted (ie copied unsuccessfully), the program will revert & keep the old version of the destination folder.

5-The batch file should run at the time i turn off my PC or at 7pm Daily.
```

So, i tried this

```
xcopy C:\MyProject N:\backup\MyProject /V /Y /E /D
```

Note: /v=Verify, /y=No prompting /e=subdirs /d=Copy only changed

However, after running the batch, it did not delete the files/folders mentioned in requirement 2. Also, i don't know how to do the requirement 4 & 5.

I searched many questions but seem they didn't have the code to meet requirement 2 & 4  & 5.

I don't want to use backup tool in Win7 since it is very heavy & it requires a big backup disk space. I prefer something simple (why didn't Window make things simple?? ).

Backup is very important when u do the project, I hope my question will help a lot of other programmers.

Can anyone know a good solution for this?

Comment: Look at `robocopy /mir`.

Comment: so "Robocopy /mir" meet the requirement 1?
or do i need to use "/xo"to make it meet requirement 1?

Comment: Yes i just confirmed that "robocopy c:\MyFolder d:\Backup /MIR" does everything you are asking for except maybe the failure restore thing. Wish I had known about robocopy before as its brilliant compared to manual xcpoy batch files!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a mirror backup, which only copies new and changed files, removes files that no longer exist in the source - then Robocopy is built in and can do that.  A batch file that is scheduled at 7pm daily will work.

Your requirement #4 is something that I haven't seen in any backup programs, including Robocopy.

Comment: id "Robocopy /mir" meet the requirement 1?

Comment: also how to check to make sure the program leave out the unmodified files?

Comment: Robocopy doesn't copy files that are the same name/size and timestamp.

Comment: `/XO Excludes files tagged as "Older".`  It has this switch but Robocopy has different versions in each Windows from Vista and onward.  You will have to check if yours has /XO switch.  XP has a version that is downloadable from Microsoft.

Comment: i tested, using /xo or not to use /xo doesn't make any difference in Win7. Thank you very much for you help.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a batch file like this for an old XP machine, since I didn't trust the format produced by NTbackup to be readable on future machines. E.g. Windows 7 and 8 require a download of some sort of converter: forget that. My batch file lives in the root C:\ directory, and I have a shortcut in my "tools" program list.

Write the file in Notepad, and save as e.g. c:\backup.bat. Run it from the "Run" command. The first time it runs, all the directories you specify will be copied exactly to your backup drive, including all subdirectories (I use a 4 Gbyte thumb drive: you may well need larger). The first time, my small 3 GB or so of stuff took about 4 minutes on an old XP machine.

Interestingly, the total uncompressed backup produced this way is no larger than the backup produced by NTbackup in Windows XP in that program's unreadable format.

Here's a batch file, with comments (REM)...

REM backup.bat

The xcopy line below is for stuff in directory c:\anydir and its subdirectories, being copied to a directory \anydir on an e: drive (e.g. USB drive).

REM The actual command:

xcopy c:\anydir e:\anydir /i /s /y /d

For other directories, just change the c:\directory and e:\directory names in the xcopy command. Watch out, however, for names like My Pictures, with a space: you must rename them (just delete the space), so that DOS recognizes them.

REM finish

exit

The /i means make any (sub)directories that don't exist on the backup drive. This therefore copies the whole branch from the c: directory where you start.

The /s copies source directories and subdirectories unless they are empty.

The /y says don't ask about over-writing existing files.

The /d says only copy files of a later date: perfect for backup, and very fast.

The files are exactly as original: no weird backup format.

With regard to the questioner's question #4, I think just running the backup again would overwrite any failure. But if that fails, wipe your backup drive and start over. And question #5...XP (and I think 7) allow scheduled tasks from the Startup menu: just insert c:\backup.bat in the list. But I haven't tried that.